# React native - Drag up modal from bottom while swiping up on the screen

Tags: android, ios, react-native, swipe, gesture

How would one slowly drag a modal up when swiping up on the screen, drag it up completley if swiped up fast and close when swiped down.

This is just like how Snapchat works in the video shown bellow.

[image]

I have tried [react-native-swipe-modal-up-down](https://github.com/MinaSamir11/react-native-swipe-modal-up-down) and [react-native-modalize](https://github.com/jeremybarbet/react-native-modalize) but they both don't support showing it slowly while swiping up the screen when its fully hidden.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `react-native-bottom-sheet` for that
https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet

you can install it using `yarn add @gorhom/bottom-sheet@^4`

check out the docs: https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of solutions.
One of the best implementations I have seen was [this](https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet)

Also, I recommend you to watch this on youtube, it builds something similar. Check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KvRqsRwpwhY&t=171s)

> For implementing I would suggest using one of these because they use
> react-native-gesture-handler and reanimated, and those run in UI
> thread, which is a lot faster and does not block the javascript thread.

Hope it helps, if you have any questions please ask.

> EDITED

### **ANSWER**

Here I am writing a sample code.
This can be implemented easily with a scroll-view, I will do it with react-native-reanimated so if you want more animation you can edit and extend it. That youtube video up has another video where he implements something similar.

I won't implement full navigation, just an example but so you will know how to do it

- I am assuming you want full-screen navigation

Create your screens (I will create one screen us it twice for example I will call it a page)

```
//page.js
import React from 'react';
import { Dimensions, View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
interface PageProps {
  index: number;
  title: string;
}

const Page: React.FC<PageProps> = ({ index, title }) => {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: `rgba(0,0,50, 0.${index + 2})` }]}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    height: Dimensions.get('screen').height - Constants.statusBarHeight, // this is important if you want full screen navigation
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 60,
    color: 'white',
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
});

export { Page };
```

```
// Than on another place use an animated scroll

import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';
import { Page } from './map/Page';

const TestScreen = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <Animated.ScrollView pagingEnabled style={styles.container}>
{/* so here are your screens, for example first camera second images */}
      <Page title={'PAGE 1 '} index={0} />
      <Page title={'PAGE 2'} index={1} />
    </Animated.ScrollView>
  );
};

export default TestScreen;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});
```

Here is a small gif showing the implementation.

[image]

> I used animated scroll-view but you can use just normal scroll view. This is with expo but is the same in react native too. I have implemented with reanimated because it is more performant when you will start to implement scroll-view inside the page(screen) because then you will have to check and handle which scroll-view is active.

If you have any questions please ask.

Comment: Thanks. Well this is just like the libraries, a bottom modal that you press a button to open, then you can drag it up more with swipe gestures on the modal itself. What I want is to open it by swiping on the screen, if you get what I mean.

Comment: Hello, please check again, I have implemented the same thing you want, where you can scroll between two pages, but the hard cases will come when you want to implement again a scroll view inside the page because you will have to configure and check which scroll view is active. If you want to know how to implement then check that library I wrote up, because he did it really well. Please ask if this does not fit your answer. Test it, and i think this is the answer you want. :)

Comment: Could work, but not for my case. I dont want the old page to scroll away. I want the new page to scroll up over it.